# Statistical Significance with large data sets

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, large-data

When I was a Ph.D. student I was trained in no uncertain terms that

When we had large numbers of data results, that the number of significant results HAD to be, in and of themselves SIGNIFICANT!

I am referring to the use and abuse of statistical significance in a large data set using different methodologies of predictive analytics.

I would appreciate if anyone could kindly offer constructive comments with reference to this issue.

Thank you

Comment: "[L]arge numbers of data results" is ambiguous as between (a) the effects of a large sample size and (b) those of trying many different tests or methods. Also, you have tagged this **both** sample-size **and** effect-size. Please think up a better title too: "Tricky question" is useless for the purposes of people searching this site for advice. This is not a helpline but a site with the aim of building up an archive of well-answered good questions. (Your title is likely to be edited any way by anyone with enough reputation; I am tempted to do it myself, but as above your question is unclear.)

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of significant results HAD to be [...] SIGNIFICANT"?

Comment: Thank you very much both for the provocative comments...this was intended to be a generic open question to serve as a basis for discussion and food for thought. It was not intended to be specific to elicit an answer or advice on a specific question. Please feel free to edit it so it can serve the scope and goals of the forum. Thank you Very much for your quick reply.

Comment: I'm not sure what the statement is intended to mean which makes it hard to contradict. However, [see here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf). $\,\,$  Re: "*this was intended to be a generic open question*" --- generic open questions are very likely to be off topic as 'too broad' and likely also as 'too opinion based'.

Comment: Indeed...so I most welcome your opinions as well as your insightful paper. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to re-edit it. My sincere apologies for the inconvenience this message might cause to you. Thank you for your constructive criticism and kind intention to correspond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to have a very large sample and a non-significant result. Perhaps this is simplest to demonstrate with categorical data. Suppose you have data on one condition on two groups of data, e.g. Men and women and whether last name ends in a vowel or consonant. Suppose you find, among 1,000,000 people, that exactly equal proportions of men and women have last names that end in vowels. Then the p value will be 1.00. I.e.

```
vowel <- c(rep('Y', 100000), rep('N', 900000))
sex <- c(rep('F', 50000), rep('M', 50000),
         rep('F', 450000), rep('M', 450000))

table(vowel, sex)
chisq.test(vowel, sex)
```

What is true is that, when N is very large, even trivial differences from the exact null hypothesis will be significant. e.g. in the above, if even 1% more men had a last name ending in a vowel, then p has 9 0's:

```
vowel <- c(rep('Y', 100000), rep('N', 900000))
sex <- c(rep('F', 49000), rep('M', 51000),
         rep('F', 450000), rep('M', 450000))

table(vowel, sex)
chisq.test(vowel, sex)
```

Comment: Your example is very interesting thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to not use the word "significant" alone. Speak of "statistical significance" because this is how the term was historically settled, and speak of substantive "importance", like for example "economic importance", (this will depend on context) to talk about whether an effect or an association that appears to exist (i.e. *given* that it is "statistically significant"), it is also (or not) "important" -which relates to its actual size and magnitude and whether, in the end, its existence matters or not. Of course this is *opinion*, but in Social Sciences, opinions are equally important.

As an example, assume that a researcher determines statistically, that a government initiative had a "statistically significant" effect on the targeted phenomenon -say "jobs creation". Fine. While I consider this part of the research *indispensable*, I would want then the researcher to discuss the *size* of the effect, relative to the target, the situation, etc.,  and *form an evidence-based argument* as to whether this "statistically significant" result "matters", not as a value-judgement, but quantitatively.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful suggestion. I did this further revision of the title...Although I would like to extend it not only on statistical significance but on practical significance as well...Thank you again for your comment.

Comment: You're welcome -but now you would have to clarify what you mean by "practical significance"!

Comment: Well...I would quote Patrick M. Baldasare example example of practical significance here: http://www.quirks.com/articles/a1994/19941101.aspx which is in pretty layman terms but sensible to my humble opinion.

Comment: From what I read in the link, by "practical significance" the author tries to make essentially the same distinction with the one I attempted to make in my answer.